# How to Run Single SQL query multiple times with different values in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have below queries in MySQLWorkbench

```
    Select * from table where col1 = "A" and col2 = "a"   
    Select * from table where col1 = "B" and col2 = "b"  
    Select * from table where col1 = "C" and col2 = "c"  
    Select * from table where col1 = "D" and col2 = "d"  
    Select * from table where col1 = "E" and col2 = "e"
```

can i make those queries into one query like this

```
Select * from table where col1 = <value1> and col2 =<value2>
```

where it read the values from file (or somewhere) and assign it to query and run.

I think, i can store value in below format

```
A,a
B,b
C,b
D,d
E,e
```

Comment: Use `IN` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting something which you pass parameters to?

If so, the following procedure will work

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProc
(
    IN Val1 VARCHAR(10),
    IN Val2 VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = Val1 AND col2 = Val2;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How to call Stored procedure multiple times with different set of values passed each time.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
select
    *
from
    table
where
    (col1 ='A' and col2 = 'a')
    OR (col1= 'B' and col2 = 'b')
    OR (col1 = 'C' and col2 = 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
Select 
       * 
from 
       table 
where 
       col1 IN ('A','B','C','D','E') and col2=LOWER(col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like i suggested in comment, you can use `IN` operator:
You can read more about [**here**](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php).

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col1 IN ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") and col2 IN ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```